# What is the difference between being imaginative and creative?

Tags: differences, adjectives

I cannot understand the difference between being imaginative and creative, sometimes I get either of the words but thinking or relating  it to the other confuses me and I reach back to where I started. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Which dictionaries have you consulted?

Comment: 'imaginative' is more about talking, 'creative' more about making.

Comment: @Mitch I'am not entirely agree with you on this point; as far as I know, imaginative persons tend to be stereotyped as a dreamers, and the stereotype may be fair; while creative persons are motivated by the desire to achieve, not by the desire to beat others. So, it is difficult to see the difference you stated.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: I was giving the simplest not incorrect difference: thoughts vs. reality. 'Make' means to 'create' or 'build' here.

Comment: @Mitch I might say, 'imaginative' is more about *thinking*, 'creative' more about making.

Comment: @Jim: I can be imaginative all day in my own head, but nobody else will know about it unless I tell thm.

Comment: @Mitch That's my point- you can be imaginative all day in your head.  That means imagination is about thinking. If you later choose to tell people about the things you were imagining then you are certainly free to do so whether by talking, writing, drawing or Morse code.

Answer (score 2):

The literal interpretation is that while they both come up with new, interesting ideas, the creative person follows up and creates the things he or she imagines, while an imaginative person merely has ideas.